# Adding label in header of *.docx files by Python

Tags: python, label, python-docx

I have a question:
I'm working on a project that automatically insert text-label in the header of .docx files in the current folder using Python and **python-docx**.
But it can not do anything.
Here is the code. Sorry for some bad executions. I'm just an amateur in this coding thing.

```
from docx import Document
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
print(path)

def label(docFileName):
    document = Document(docFileName)
    section = document.sections[0]
    header = section.header
    header

    header.is_linked_to_previous = True

    header = document.sections[0].header
    paragraph = header.paragraphs[0]
    paragraph.text = "Left Header\t[CONFIDENTIAL]\tRight Header"
    paragraph.style = document.styles["Normal"]

    return print("Labeled")

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".docx"):
        docFileName = os.path.join(path,file)
        print(docFileName)
        label(docFileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the format.  I used this command to add a sequence number to a filename.  You can use strings or other similar values and if you have multiples of things, just put them in sequence separated by commas.

filename = ('h:\docx test_{}.docx')
filename = filename.format(cnt)

Here's another example in my current code where it replace longer string values

temp_str = "'ID': '{}', 'Year': '{}', 'Reference': '{}', 'hyperlink': '{}'"
new_str = temp_str.format(id_str, year_str, r_str, h_str)

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `header.is_linked_to_previous = True` line. That essentially deletes the header. If you are purposely deleting an existing header, then set `header.is_linked_to_previous = False` after the `header = document.sections[0].header` line, before accessing its paragraphs.